# UserService.createLoginURL results in "The page you requested is invalid." error

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication

I am using UserService to redirect to login page:

```
String loginURL = userService.createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI());
throw new ModelAndViewDefiningException(new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(loginURL, false)));
```

This is resulting in URL like:

https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%253Fcontinue%253Dhttp://www.example.com/logingoogle.htm&ltmpl=gm&ahname=example&sig=5291e6bad7249c73c4968655133c87c5

(example = my domain name)

when someone is redirected, Google displays page with error:

> The page you requested is invalid.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
This is so annoying, I tried to find solution for this - without any luck.

This is happening with GAE JDK 1.4.3 (Java)

Exactly same code was working in version 1.3.2, after a while I decided to play again with GAE, upgraded libraries ... and now I have issue with logging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem today with GAE 1.6.3.

The login does not work with the URL you have given above:

https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%253Fcontinue%253Dhttp://www.example.com/logingoogle.htm&ltmpl=gm&ahname=example&sig=5291e6bad7249c73c4968655133c87c5

But it works if you replace "*https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?*" with "*https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?*" like this:

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%253Fcontinue%253Dhttp://www.example.com/logingoogle.htm&ltmpl=gm&ahname=example&sig=5291e6bad7249c73c4968655133c87c5

Unfortunately it is not possible to modify the URL, since it is generated by UserService.
But i could get my app to generate the second URL in this way:

The default page of my app has initially directed requests through a "jsp:forward" to the controller that checked if the user was logged in. I have changed my app so that the requests are processed at first place by the controller (without a previous forward). That solved my problem. But i can't explain what lies behind this misbehaviour.

Comment: Thank, good while ago I abandoned GAE. It took more time to invent workarounds for it's limitations, than actual working on applications ...